# Using the Tweet Parser to print likes, comments, and shares on Twitter posts

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

I'm new to Python, and I've been learning about using API. I've recently found the Tweet Parser: https://pypi.org/project/tweet-parser/

How could I (using BS4 instead) print only the number of likes, comments and shares on a Tweet? And could it be used with the [Public Twitter APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index) instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check out [twpy](https://github.com/0x0ptim0us/twpy) lib:

- NO LIMIT, NO API required
- Fast and easy to use
- Working with python 3.6+
- Integrated with pandas for data science research

Comment: Thanks for replying - I am specifically looking to use API though!